# Java : How to convert java.lang.String to ISO 8859-1 format

Tags: java, encoding, iso

In my application, i'm parsing ISO 8859-1 formatted data via CSVParser. But when i store parsed data to a String array, then cross check with corresponding ISO 8859-1 formatted data in the database, the string array not supporting some character mapping(Eg: µ is encoded as ?).This is my parsing code :

```
CSVReader reader;
    List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<String[]>();
    try {
        reader = new CSVReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(directory))), Configuration.CSV_SEPERATOR);

        list = reader.readAll();    
for (String[] singleStock : list) {
}
```

String[] singleStock, is used to hold parsed data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify [CharSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html) while creating [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader%28java.io.InputStream,%20java.nio.charset.Charset%29)

Example:

```
new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(directory)),Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Answer (score 4):

The InputStreamReader will need to know the stream is ISO 8859-1 format. Try adding this parameter to the InputStreamReader...

```
new InputStreamReader( ... , Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1"))
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to use another constructor for [InputStreamReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html)

```
InputStreamReader(InputStream in, String charsetName) 
Create an InputStreamReader that uses the named charset.
```